# How do I find an angle between two medians of triangle?

Tags: vectors, median

I have a hard time solving math task, which I have to do with vectors. I will post the photo of the triangle given in the task. Currently I am solving quite a lot of exercises with vectors, however I feel lost on this one.

The task:

Right triangle $ABC$, $\angle C$ is 90 degrees. The cosine of acute angle $\angle A$ is $\frac{\sqrt6}{3}$. Find angle between medians $CD$ and $BE$.

[image: Triangle]

Comment: Show us what you tried.  If you are learning about vectors, then how about you try to place the figure on a coordinate plane and define some vectors for the vertices?  What happens when you do this?  How does the desired quantity (the angle between two line segments) then translate to some property of vectors?

Comment: I know that a * b = |a| * |b| * cos<x. However, I don't have the lenghts of vectors. I am not sure what you mean by saying to put triangle on coordinate plane. If I would put it on the coordinate plane the lenghts of vectors wouldn't be accurate.

Comment: Choose one of the points to be the origin and without loss of generality, you can select one segment to have length $1$, because the desired angle will not change if the figure is scaled.  Then, what would be the positions of some of the other vectors?